# move_uploaded_file is not WORKING

Tags: php

I have a code. But move_uploaded_file is not working.

This is my code below:

is there any way to upload all types of  with one field like Image/Video?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_news']))
{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$location="news/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$vfile=$_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
$vid= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['video']['tmp_name']));
$video_name= addslashes($_FILES['video']['name']);
$video ="news/" . $_FILES['video']['name'];


$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(video,image) VALUES('$video',
'$location')");

if(!$q)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],"../news/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../news/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$_SESSION['mass_added']= 'echo"you are logged in"';
echo "<script>window.location = 'manage_news.php?user_type=admin'</script>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: try just dumping them in the root folder first and see if that works: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],"/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);

Comment: Is the required permission there for the script to write the files in news directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the errors to find out why.  Do this by looking at `$_FILES['video']['error']`.

My guess would be that if you're uploading videos, their filesize is too large.  You can change the maximum upload file size in php.ini with `upload_max_filesize=..." ([see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)).